# Pupillometry: how long needs the pupil to respond towards an cognitive stimuli?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, vision, eye-movement

I would like to know if somebody could give me some references on the latency of the pupil response after a cognitive stimulus.

I know that the light reflex is quite fast compared to cognitive stimulation, but I could not find more information than this. Does anyone know how long it takes the pupil to react toward a cognitive task? Or a good reference where I could read it on my own?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do?  If you're trying to leverage pupil-dilation data from an eye-tracker, there are ways to deconvolute the timeseries if you can make a strong inference as to exactly when the stimulus of interest took place.

I think you'll find everything you're looking for [here](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Niels_Taatgen/publication/224958750_Pupil_dilation_deconvolution_reveals_the_dynamics_of_attention_at_high_temporal_resolution/links/0fcfd506c99e4e468c000000.pdf).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. :)  I was just reading this article. They mentioned once that it takes some time for the pupil size to increase and that it achieves its peak at around 1 second. But do you maybe know any other studies showing the pupil dilation latencies?  thanks

Comment: @dabunar, Check the references in the paper I linked to.  They pretty much hit every major paper on the subject!  Also, please accept the answer if it gave you the information you're looking for!